# I can get specific object with json dict but not json array

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

This json file:

```
[ {
  "irc_server" : null,
  "ssh_keys" : [ ],
  "branches" : {
    "master" : {
      "running_builds" : [ ],
      "recent_builds" : [ {
        "outcome" : "no_tests",
        "status" : "no_tests",
        "build_num" : 1,
        "vcs_revision" : "748f8679cfc850582e3ada08210d8566a291328c",
        "pushed_at" : "2017-07-21T03:39:46.230Z",
        "added_at" : "2017-07-21T03:36:24.657Z"
      } ],
      "last_non_success" : {
        "outcome" : "no_tests",
        "status" : "no_tests",
        "build_num" : 1,
        "vcs_revision" : "748f8679cfc850582e3ada08210d8566a291328c",
        "pushed_at" : "2017-07-21T03:39:46.230Z",
        "added_at" : "2017-07-21T03:36:24.657Z"
      }
    }
  }]
```

How I parse it:

```
        projectsurl = get(API_PATH['PROJECTS'].format(self._token))  #get json data from url

        decodedjson = projectsurl.content.decode('utf-8') #decode to string

        jsondata = json.loads(decodedjson) #json obj

        return jsondata['vcs_revision']
```

How can i get a specific object from this array? Whenever I call `return jsondata['vcs_revision']` It says i need an int not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `jsondata[0]['vcs_revision']` because your `jsondata` is a list of dicts.

Comment: That fixed the issue, should I delete this question or keep it?

Comment: Great. It's up to you what to do with the question. No one will care if you leave it.